# How to get DOM elements within (any/all) nested components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a wrapper component in my App as follows. I have logic in the wrapper component that gets the DOM nodes with props.children that have a specific data attribute.

When the DOM elements are direct children, this works fine. When they are children of any nested component they're not found. How can I iterate through the entire structure and get all instances of the DOM nodes by attr?

I'm new to react and sure this should be straightforward, however I've not been able to implement from a number of examples / SO answers. I've tried to implement useRef and useContext hooks but can't get this?

```
// App.js

<Wrapper>        

   <div data-elem></div> // Get's found
   <Component {...pageProps}  />

</Wrapper>


// index.js

const Page = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div data-elem></div> // Not found
      </>
    );
}


// Wrapper.js ( simplified version )

export default function Wrapper(props) {

  const detectedElements = props.children.filter((item) => item.props['data-elem'] === true);
  console.log(detectedElements.length)

  return (

     <div className="wrapper">
        {children}
     </div>

  )

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a state variable in the parent and then pass the update state variable function to the child? Once the child content changes call the update state variable function to update the parent state variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. To clarify do you mean child here as in the DOM elements within the nested components? And would this not then be dependent on the DOM element's state changing? I'd like to be able simply to 'get' the elements, for example to find the length of them all off the bat in the first case - I imagined useContext would be appropriate there, but couldn't achieve the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I managed to achieve this simply by using `querySelectorAll` within the useEffect hook. I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' way to do it, but is definitely the most straightforward of the the variations I tried, and seems to do the job, regardless of where the corresponding elements are.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const detectedElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-elem]')
}, []);
```